# True or False : Every root of a cubic equation has closed expression

Tags: trigonometry, cubics

I know that statement is right in many examples but when I wanted to find exact value of $10$ degree , I achieved this equation : $8t^3 - 6t + 1 = 0$ where $t = \sin10$ . Also I know we have a nested radical expression for it (See :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi18.html ) And contradiction appears when it's a root of equation and we can also solve it by Cardano's method and this gives us a closed formula for $\sin 10$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Where is the contradiction?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I want to know how it is possible that a root of cubic equation be infinity nested radical.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt And also how we can get this nested radical solution from $8t^3 - 6t + 1 = 0$ equation ?

Comment: SHW why are you talking about nested radicals? Do you have an explicit example of that? There are some questions on this site that used such things; but, they are less general than one might expect.

Comment: take a look at this item by Tito: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065862/something-strange-about-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-x-x-and-its-friends

Comment: You seem to talk about the constructibility with ruler and compass. Square-roots can be constructed this way, but not irrational cubic-roots. There is no possibility to construct $\sin(10°)$ with ruler and compass because the minimal polynomial has degree $3$. So, there is no contradiction to the solveability by Cardanos formula (which always works, but requires ugly roots of complex numbers in the case of $3$ real numbers)

Comment: @WillJagy My problem is how solving $8t^3 - 6t + 1 = 0$ leads us to that nested radical in (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi18.html ) ?

Comment: @Peter This is good point thank you but my problem isn't this.

Comment: @Peter This is my problem : How solving $8t^3 - 6t + 1 = 0$ can leads us to that nested radical in (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi18.html ) ?

Comment: @Peter Is my question clear now ?

Comment: @S.H.W OK, I understand. These formulas give a way to construct $\sin(10^°)$, but with infinite many steps. Maybe, you can get some fix-point property by only considerting three nested square-roots. I am not sure, but a similar approach allows to calculate easier nested square-roots, but I have nothing concrete.

Comment: @Peter Okay , Previously I asked it but really didn't understand how it's related to that equation . (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001269/value-of-sin-pi-18-by-nested-radicals)

Comment: shw I have it.... typing answer with pictures

Comment: @WillJagy Okay , Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Peter posted an answer. The important point is not the infinite nesting, it is the recurrence, where the variable I called $x$ appears both on the left hand side of the equation  and inside the radicals on the right hand side. Put another way, we have a fixpoint of a real function.

Comment: @WillJagy Nice!

Comment: It is quite easy to get the value of $2\sin\frac{\pi}{18}$ as follows. Refer [here][1] and also for $2\cos\frac{\pi}{18}$. But my attempt to solve $2\cos\frac{\pi}{18}$ as $\frac{\sqrt3}{6}\cdot(\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8-\sqrt{8+...}}}+1)$ is not successful currently


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001269/value-of-sin-pi-18-by-nested-radicals/3994234#3994234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $$ x = 2 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{18} \right) \approx 0.347296 > \frac{1}{3} $$
we are told
$$ x = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + x} }}.  $$
Put another way, we are demanding a fixpoint of the real valued function
$$ f(w) = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + w} }}. $$

I repeatedly squared and put the polynomial terms on one side, which led to
$$ x^8 - 8 x^6 + 20 x^4 - 16 x^2 - x + 2 = 0. $$ This factors,
$$ \left(x-2 \right)   \left( x+1 \right)  \left(x^3 + x^2 - 2x+1 \right)  \left( x^3 - 3x + 1\right)    $$
You can see from the graphs that $x \approx 0.347$ can only be a root of the final cubic, $x^3 - 3x + 1.$ Call your quantity $s$ so that $x = 2s,$ we get $8 s^3 - 6 s + 1 = 0.$

[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice that, while the octic polynomial has eight real roots, the original function has just a single real fixpoint.
[image]

Comment: Oh , Very good answer . Now I solved equation with Wolfram and it gives a complicated answer. Do you know an easy expression for $\sin 10$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W easy, no. There is Cardano's formula, as Peter mentioned. If you ever study Galois theory, you will begin to understand. As Peter also said, your $\sin 10^\circ$ falls under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good one. Find the roots of
$$  x^3 + x^2 - 4 x + 1. $$
Very trigonometric.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more about your answer ?

Comment: @S.H.W just a good example, with quite pretty outcome. I still have no idea what your question is. Since this has three real irrational roots, it falls under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis  However, very nice answer if we include trigonometric functions.